# Export plot in .png with transparent background

Tags: r, plot, png

I am trying to export a simple plot in *.png* with transparent background. I am able to export it, but the background stays white.

**Mock example**

```
x = c(1, 2, 3)
```

**I've tried this**

```
plot (x)

dev.copy (png,'myplot.png', bg = 'transparent')
dev.off()
```

**And this**

```
plot (x, bg = 'transparent')

dev.copy (png,'myplot.png')
dev.off()
```

But neither work.

Can someone help?

Comment: try: `png("myplot.png", width=600, height=400, bg = "transparent"); plot(x); dev.off()`

Comment: It worked for me with `plot (x, bg = 'transparent'); dev.copy (png,'myplot.png',  bg = 'transparent')  `

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
x = c(1, 2, 3)
par(bg=NA)
plot (x)

dev.copy(png,'myplot.png')
dev.off()
```

Comment: and how would one revert the `par` change?

Comment: Creating an object with default parametrs: ´parOrig <- par()´  and using it as an ´par()´ argument: ´par(parOrig)´
´parOrig <- par(); 
par(bg=NA, mfrow = c(2, 1));
plot (1:3);
par(parOrig);
plot (1:3)´

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saving all parameters, it is better to only save the old value of the parameter that was changed in a call to ´par´ by saving result of ´par´ as in the modified example:

```
x = c(1, 2, 3)
old.par <- par(bg=NA)
plot (x)

dev.copy(png,'myplot.png')
dev.off()
par(old.par)
```