# How to create a Venn diagram with a transparent background in R?

Tags: r, graphics, venn-diagram

I'm using the package "VennDiagram" and used it to generate a nice plot. However I need to export it with a transparent background so that I can use it on a poster. Saving it as a .png directly didn't work, and neither did `par(bg=NA)`. Any suggestions? I'm also willing to try a different package as my diagram is fairly simple.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43614863/export-plot-in-png-with-transparent-background

Comment: I tried using par=bg(NA) but it still had a white background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me: (from [Export plot in .png with transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43614863/export-plot-in-png-with-transparent-background).)

```
library(gplots)
png("~/venn_test.png", bg = 'transparent')
venn(list(A = letters[sample(26, 10)],
       B = letters[sample(26, 10)],
       C = letters[sample(26, 10)]))
dev.off()
```

Comment: Using gplots worked and is also much simpler than VennDiagram. Thanks!